# preg_replace not working!

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-replace

Here's my Codeigniter function:

```
function edit_phone($phone)
{
            if (preg_match('/^\(?[0-9]{3}\)?[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$/', $phone))
            {
                return preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2-$3", $phone); 
            }
            else
            {
               $this->CI->validation->set_message('phone', "This must be a 10-digit USA phone number.");
                    return FALSE;       
            }
}
```

This validates/checks the input alright, but doesn't reformat it in the db.

Validation is great!  But why isn't this returning a standard phone number?!

Comment: maybe you don't save the return value of edit_phone?

Comment: Ahh, you could be correct!  Could you give me an example?  I'm new at this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that it will ONLY work with a number in the format 1234567890, but based on the regular expression in the preg_match() call, Kevin is also looking to accommodate numbers like:

- (123)4567890
- (123) 456 7890
- 123-456-7890

If so, the regex in the preg_replace() needs to be something like...

`preg_replace('/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/', "$1-$2-$3", $phone)`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please give us example data, that you tried to fill in?

I used the following code:

```
$phone = "1234567890";
echo preg_replace("/([0-9]{3})([0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})/", "$1-$2-$3", $phone);
```

and got:

```
123-456-7890
```

which is absolutely correct, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I believe Michael is correct.  Could you please tell me how I would grab the return?

Comment: `$phone_number = edit_phone("1234567890");` the return value is now in `$phone_number`